# Tesseract 3.03: 'boxchar.lo' is not a valid libtool object

Tags: gcc, tesseract, autotools, libtool

I have been trying to compile `Tesseract 3.03 rc1` these days. I have tried `Cygwin`, `MinGW+MSYS`, `MSYS2+MinGW-w64`. And now I am using the `Xubuntu 15.04`.

The `3.03 rc1` source is downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7l10Bj_LprhQnpSRkpGMGV2eE0&usp=sharing).

I have successfully compiled the `tesseract` with `make install`.

But when I trying to compile the training tools with `make training`, I see the following error:

[image]

Anyone could shed some light on this?? I am kind of out of clue now.

(BTW, I see someone mentioned the `tesseract 3.04`. But I can only find the `3.03 rc1` at [google's location](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7l10Bj_LprhQnpSRkpGMGV2eE0&usp=sharing). Anyone know where the `3.04` is?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=1458) and turn to compile `tesseract 3.03.03`, it compiles OK so far. I will continue update my progress.